# Filtering an array to remove items and returning back an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array and I need to exclude some items from it I use this code but this doesn't always work. or should this work at all times. then I am doing something else wrong

```
let ar = this.comments.filter(vc => {
   return vc !== this.id
});
this.myarr = ar ..
```

Comment: On a first view, there seems nothing wrong. What exactly does not work?

Comment: I use firebase and make a request on a nuxt spa but when I do multiple deletions and refresh page somethings doesn't apply I thought this might be it, thanks for answer

Comment: If the filtered items are objects and they have an `id`, you probably want to filter them using `this.comments.filter(c => c.id !== this.id)`. How does a comment look like?

Comment: Your code looks correct, at least if you want to remove all entries of value „this.id“ from „this.comments“ the problem must be somewhere else (e.g. the value of this.id changes or you have some async race conditions.

Comment: array of items ['a', 'b']

Comment: I think since I have many of the same components rendered in the page I might need to use vuexstore. I tried it this morning didn't work but I have to find a solution I will eventually.

Comment: In that case, when `this.id` matches `'a'` or `'b'`, what you have now, which could be written shorter as `this.comments.filter(c => c !== this.id)` will filter whatever `this.id` is out. Consider adding more code to your question, as the problem you have does not appear to happen in what you've shared so far.

Comment: Maybe unrelated but, I believe code runs from top to bottom, by any chance would it jump over some code and keeps running rest and then completing the one that takes longer at the top?

Answer (score -1):

problem of code for use "this" inside of filter loop.

```
let that = this
let ar = this.comments.filter(vc => {
      return vc !== that.id
    })
this.myarr = ar ..
```

Comment: Your answer would be true if he didn't use an arrow function (i.e: `const this = that; this.comments.filter(function(c) { return c !== that.id})`, but ***he is*** using an arrow function, so `this` inside it ***is*** the outer `this`. In other words, `c => c` is the exact equivalent of `c => { return c; }`. They both use the outer `this`, as they're both arrow functions. First one is a shorthand of the second, that's all.

Comment: Curly braces not needed `let ar = this.comments.filter(vc => vc !== that.id)`